# Can a member function pointer refer to a method of one of several different classes?

Tags: c++, casting, c++17, function-pointers, pointer-to-member

This is what I have:

```cpp
class Foo;
class Bar;
class FooBar 
{
public:
        FooBar( Foo &f, void ( Foo::* signal )( FooBar* ) ) 
                : m_Foo(&f)
                , fp_Foo(signal) {};
        FooBar( Bar &b, void ( Bar::* signal )( FooBar* ) ) 
                : m_Bar(&b)
                , fp_Bar(signal) {};

protected:
        void ( Foo::*fp_Foo )( FooBar* );
        void ( Bar::*fp_Bar )( FooBar* );

private: 
        Foo *m_Foo{nullptr};
        Bar *m_Bar{nullptr};
};
```

This is what I want:

```cpp
class Foo;
class Bar;
class FooBar 
{
public:
        FooBar( Foo &f, void ( Foo::* signal )( FooBar* ) ) 
                : m_Foo(&f)
                , fp(signal) {};
        FooBar( Bar &b, void ( Bar::* signal )( FooBar* ) ) 
                : m_Bar(&b)
                , fp(signal) {};

protected:
        void ( <???>::*fp )( FooBar* ); // Deduplicated

private: 
        Foo *m_Foo{nullptr};
        Bar *m_Bar{nullptr};
};
```

I want only one set of member function pointers, that can stand in for both `Foo` and `Bar`.

Is this possible without the use of a template?

Thanks.

Comment: QList is not a QObject. Subclass QObject and compose the subclass with a list.

Comment: I think dropping Qt from this question would help make it far clearer. Are you asking if a member data pointer taken using a derived class the same as that pointer taken from the base class?

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux, the OP has an XY problem. Qt is right in the tags. And the solution is already given.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Yeah that is true enough. I'll edit the question and take out the Qt cruft seeing as it has already wasted someones time. `Are you asking if a member data pointer taken using a derived class the same as that pointer taken from the base class?` no.

Comment: @Anon I don't think this is possible with member function pointers. The class is part of its type and they aren't interconvertible. You could try `std::function<void(FooBar*)>` instead. Otherwise, you can try using a template.

Comment: I know I'm late to the party, but... The edit was not a success. Instead of a question that was specific, practical and useful, you've created a question that is none of these things. I recommend re-asking the original question.

Comment: @Anon I just wanted to check if I understood the issue correctly and if any of my suggestions would work?

Comment: @TedLyngmo I did not use your solution [Being a qt developer, I tend to avoid the stdlib unless absolutely neccessary]. What I did instead, is I made a base class containing the functions (Qt signals actually), and just had my classes based on that, if that makes sense.

Comment: @Anon Sort of... but could you write an answer to your question as it currently stands? I noticed that you previously had Qt in the question but that's not the question I answered. Also: The last part of my answer doesn't use any of the stdlib.

Answer (score 2):

One option is to use a [`std::function`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) in which you store a lambda that calls what you want to call:

```cpp
#include <functional>

class FooBar {
public:
    FooBar(Foo& f, void (Foo::*signal)(FooBar*)) : m_f{[&]{ (f.*signal)(this); }}
    {};
    FooBar(Bar& b, void (Bar::*signal)(FooBar*)) : m_f{[&]{ (b.*signal)(this); }}
    {};

    void call() {
        m_f();
    }

private:
    std::function<void()> m_f;
};
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/EosGx5zz6)

If you prefer to have the instance and member function pointer available, you can use a `union` to accomplish this. Since you are using C++17, you should however prefer using a [`std::variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant).

Here's an example of how that could look:

```cpp
#include <utility>
#include <variant>

class FooBar {
public:
    FooBar(Foo& f, void (Foo::*signal)(FooBar*)) : m_fp{std::pair{&f, signal}} {};
    FooBar(Bar& b, void (Bar::*signal)(FooBar*)) : m_fp{std::pair{&b, signal}} {};

    void call() {
        std::visit([this](auto&& fb){
            auto&[i, m] = fb;
            (i->*m)(this);
        }, m_fp);
    }

private:
    // store both the instance pointer and member pointer in pairs:
    std::variant<std::pair<Foo*, void(Foo::*)(FooBar*)>,
                 std::pair<Bar*, void(Bar::*)(FooBar*)>> m_fp;
};
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/czsrr8daP)

If you for some reason do not want to use a `std::variant` and `std::pair`s, just create a similar `union`:

```cpp
struct foopair {
    Foo* i;
    void (Foo::*m)(FooBar*);
};

struct barpair {
    Bar* i;
    void (Bar::*m)(FooBar*);
};

union foobaru {
    foobaru(Foo& f, void (Foo::*signal)(FooBar*)) : fp{&f, signal} {};
    foobaru(Bar& b, void (Bar::*signal)(FooBar*)) : bp{&b, signal} {};    
    foopair fp;
    barpair bp;
};

class FooBar {
public:
    FooBar(Foo& f, void (Foo::*signal)(FooBar*)) :
        has_foo{true}, m_fb{f, signal} {};
    FooBar(Bar& b, void (Bar::*signal)(FooBar*)) :
        has_foo{false}, m_fb{b, signal} {};

    void call() {
        if(has_foo) {
            auto&[i, m] = m_fb.fp;
            (i->*m)(this);
        } else {
            auto&[i, m] = m_fb.bp;
            (i->*m)(this);
        }
    }

private:
    bool has_foo;
    foobaru m_fb;
};
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/dcj7TK3zr)

Comment: Like OOP was never invented.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. Ouch :-) How would you do it?

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem.  That's what we had after OOP was invented and used originally. OOP predated implementation of classes in programming languages. :P

Comment: I would say those methods\constructor can be templates?

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie OP wrote _"Is this possible without the use of a template?"_ so I tried to adhere to that. I added the second version to not use any class templates from the standard library just in case that's how far _"without the use of a template"_ was intended.

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie No it's not OOP. Not in my book. X11 is an example of OOP without classes. It has inheritance and virtual function tables. OOP in essence **is** virtual function tables. Switches over type IDs is not. (All of the above is my opinion only)

Comment: @TedLyngmo well after re-reading the question, I admit that it doesn't make sense to me in its current form. There are two pointers to unrelated objects. There is one (desired) memfun ptr. To which of the two objects is it applicable? No indication in the question.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. Perhaps I read too much into the constructors in OPs code (which is why I made the _instance_ / _memfunc*_ pairs). OP will have to say if I misinterpreted it.

Comment: An instance / memfunc* pair is just a restricted std::function. This is one way to fill the gap in the question, there are others.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. The pair allows access to the instance and memfunc pointer if that's wanted and that was my original interpretation of the question. I added the  `std::function` later in case those pointers aren't actually needed.

Answer (score 0):

To me it seems, that you have a XY problem. That is why I will concentrate on what you actually want to achieve, i.e.:

> I want to add some signals to a QList based class for insertions, changes, and removals. The Q_OBJECT macro however will not work on this:
>
> `class CardList : public QList<Card*>`

### Cause

`QList` is not a `QObject`.

### Solution

Subclass `QObject` and compose the subclass with a list.

### Example

Here is a simple example I have written for you to demonstrate the proposed solution:

```
#include <QObject>

class Card;

class CardList : public QObject // inheritance
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit CardList(QObject *parent = nullptr);

    void addCard(Card *); // emit cardAdded here
    int cardCount() const;
    Card *card(int pos);
    bool removeCard(int pos); // emit cardRemoved here

private:
    QList<Card *> m_cards; // composition

signals:
    void cardAdded(int pos);
    void cardRemoved(int pos);
};
```

Now you can have:

```
class Game : public QObject
{
    ...
private:
    CardList *m_cards;
    ...
}

class Player : public QObject
{
    ...
private:
    CardList *m_cards;
    ...
}
```

That all being said, maybe a model would suite the needs of your application better.

Comment: I don't want to redefine all the functions of QList. My question was very specific as to whether you could cast member function pointers. `That is why I will concentrate on what you actually want to achieve, i.e.:` Is in no way what I actually want to achieve, given that I would sooner just have two sets of member function pointers than to do what you are proposing.

Comment: @Anon It is your software, man. If you want to have fun, go on with it. I might be able to show you the way, but I can't (and don't want to) force you to follow it.